# Haskell implementation of De-convolution (Richardson lucy)

Tags: haskell, image-processing, deconvolution

I'm trying to implement an algorithm of de-convolution in Haskell and couldn't find a simpler one than Richardson Lucy. I looked up at the existing matlab/python implementation but am unable to understand from where to start or how exactly to implement.
The library I want to use is https://github.com/lehins/hip.
If someone can provide an outline of some implementation or some general idea about the functions with some code snippets, that would be very helpful to me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm is actually pretty straightforward.  Using the notation on the Wikipedia page for [Richardson-Lucy deconvolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richardson%E2%80%93Lucy_deconvolution), if an underlying image `u0` was convolved by a kernel `p` to produce an observed image `d`, then you can iterate the function:

```
deconvolve p d u = u * conv (transpose p) (d / conv p u)
```

over `u` with an initial starting estimate (of `d`, for example) to get a progressively better estimate of `u0`.

In HIP, the actual one-step `deconvolve` function might look like:

```
deconvolve :: Image VS X Double
           -> Image VS RGB Double
           -> Image VS RGB Double
           -> Image VS RGB Double
deconvolve p d u
  = u * conv (transpose p) (d / conv p u)
  where conv = convolve Edge
```

and you could use something like this:

```
let us = iterate (deconvolve p d) d
    u10 = us !! 10  -- ten iterations
```

An example of a full program is:

```
import Graphics.Image as I
import Graphics.Image.Interface as I
import Prelude as P

blur :: Image VS X Double
blur = blur' / scalar (I.sum blur')
  where blur' = fromLists [[0,0,4,3,2]
                          ,[0,1,3,4,3]
                          ,[1,2,3,3,4]
                          ,[0,1,2,1,0]
                          ,[0,0,1,0,0]]

deconvolve :: Image VS X Double
           -> Image VS RGB Double
           -> Image VS RGB Double
           -> Image VS RGB Double
deconvolve p d u
  = u * conv (transpose p) (d / conv p u)
  where conv = convolve Edge

main :: IO ()
main = do
  -- original underlying image
  u0 <- readImage' "images/frog.jpg" :: IO (Image VS RGB Double)
  -- the kernel
  let p = blur
  -- blurred imaged
  let d = convolve Edge p u0
  -- iterative deconvolution
  let us = iterate (deconvolve p d) d
      u1 = us !! 1 -- one iteration
      u2 = us !! 20 -- twenty iterations

  let output = makeImage (rows u0, cols u0 * 4)
        (\(r,c) ->
           let (i, c') = c `quotRem` cols u0
           in index ([u0,d,u1,u2] !! i) (r,c'))
        :: Image VS RGB Double

  writeImage "output.jpg" output
```

which generates the following image of (left-to-right) the original frog, the blurred frog, a one-fold deconvolution, and a twenty-fold deconvolution.

[image: Ribbit!]

Comment: A Buhr. Wow!! You really made my work a lot easier. I don't know but I referred to many different links and was in a complete mess where to start from. Thanks a tonne!!

Comment: Also, I need to clarify something. Is it ok if I use this code in my work?

Comment: Sure, consider it public domain.

Comment: @ A Buhr. Thank u! Also, in case you get some time, please do look up my other question <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51906824/adding-gaussian-noise-to-images-in-haskell>.